# Composer local repository not installing (for Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, repository, composer-php

I'm working on a Laravel package, I'm trying to add it to my project using the VCS option in my composer.json but it's not installing. I've tried the following

Linking to the absolute path on my Vagrant machine

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "/home/vagrant/Code/cld/gallery/packages/Notflip/cld/"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "notflip/cld": "dev-master"
},
```

Linking to the absolute path of my Windows machine

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "D:/Sites/cld/gallery/packages/Notflip/cld"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "notflip/cld": "dev-master"
},
```

But nothing is working, the project is located as follows:

[image]

I'm using Vagrant (Homestead) on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/Notflip/cld"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "notflip/cld": "*"
},
```

And adding the following to your composer.json

```
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

You'll find more info about this here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Comment: Thank you for your answer, After that I run "composer install" but I'm getting 'nothing to install or update' again.

Comment: When I do "composer update" it's trying to download from Github and failing because the repo can't be found..

Comment: Is the package name correctly set in the `composer.json` of your package?

Comment: I've tried it out locally myself. I believe the issue is that you have a package with the same name on packagist. As soon as I changed the local package name it worked for me. Could you try changing it locally to see if it works then?

Comment: Now it's letting me know the package can't be found.. Hmh i changed notflip to potvis everywhere.. We're getting closer! "    - The requested package potvis/cld could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
"

Comment: Aha! "minimum-stability": "dev", hang on still testing

Comment: You changed it in both the `composer.json` files right?

Comment: I did now. Does it have to be changed in both composer.json files? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it basicly reads the `composer.json` file from your package to determine it's name. That way it knows it's the correct package in your project's `composer.json`.

Comment: Ah no sorry! Yes I did that to, I thought you mean adding the min-stability thing to both composer.json files

Comment: @RojVroemen could you please help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70153904/1830228 ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do more or less the same as @roj-vroemen but a little bit different.

In my case a create a folder called packages in my projects directory and add my secondary packages on it.

- projects-dir

  - foo-project
  - hello-world-project
  - packages

    - my-third-party-package

On my-third-party-package composer.json I add the following lines:

```
{
    "name": "paubenetprat/my-third-party-package",
    "description": "My third party package description.",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        ...
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

After that, on my main project composer.json (`foo-project`) I add the following:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../packages/my-third-party-package",
        "options": {
            "symlink": true
        }
    }
],
"require": {
    "paubenetprat/my-third-party-package": "dev-master"
}
```

To end up you just need to run:

`composer update paubenetprat/my-third-party-package`

It's important to specify `dev-[current-project-branch]`. If you are working on a feature (`feature/whatever-your-are-doing`) on your third party package you should specify it on you main project composer:

```
"require": {
    "paubenetprat/my-third-party-package": "dev-feature/whatever-your-are-doing"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Vcs is for version controlled not local. You would probably have more luck using class map and pointing that to the package root.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with an example on how to do that please? Weird cause the "vcs" option came from a Laracasts tutorial, seems to be working on mac.